# JQtouch: Scroll to anchor in list with link

Tags: list, cordova, scroll, anchor, jqtouch

I allready have used to much time, figuring out (googling) how to make a butten, scroll down to a specific < li > in a edgetoedge list. I use JQtouch with Zepto and PhoneGap (Cordova) .

Here's my very simple example, where im trying to use html anchors. It'll not work:

```
<div id="ListPage">
 <div> <a href="#b">jump to b</a> </div>
  <div class="scroll">
 <ul>
  <li><a name="a" />Some text</li>
    .
    . 
  50 times li.... :)
    .
    .
  <li><a name="b" />Some text</li>
  .
    . 
  50 times li.... :)
    .
    .
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

I cant use ID's cause JQtouch use the id and a for page transistions..

what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help, it works for me in a separate scenario:

```
var pos = $("a[name=a]").position();
$('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: pos.top }, 'slow' );
```

Comment: Im really a javascript rookie. I dont know how to implement the script. I tryed to place it in the head section, but then the scripts after it stop working (and still nothing happens pressing the button)... I have all my pages in one html file in Div's can i then use: ('html, body') ?

Comment: you need to put this script in the click event of your button, as you mentioned in your question above. if you can put actual source, i can show you where to put the script

Comment: Thanks! I think this will work. But I have a lot of other isues I need to figure out before i can check this solved.